# Notification icons for android platforms 1.5 - 3.2

Tags: android, icons, platform-specific

My app targets Android 1.5 to 3.2 and I'm making notification icons specific to those platforms. I'm finding it difficult to correctly to organize the icons for all these versions, including h/d/ldpi versions. I know in 3.2, the qualifiers changed, so I'm trying to account for this as well.

Currently, when I launcher in 3.2, it uses an icon for 2.3. My folder structure at the moment is as follows:

- drawable
- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-hdpi-v9
- drawable-ldpi-v9
- drawable-mdpi-v11
- drawable-mdpi-v9
- drawable-v11
- drawable-xlarge

Question is which folder (including any missing ones) should I put the platform & display/density specific icons in so I target 1.5 - 3.2 correctly?

Comment: What, precisely, is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You might try the [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-notification.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&shape=square&name=example) for generating notification icons that follow conventions for different platform versions.

Comment: I try that but it doesn't tell me what platform each folder corresponds to, I'd like to understand that as well

Comment: The -v# part determines the platform version. The number is the API level and the Android release versions those correspond to are documented here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html#intro The notification icon guidelines were the same until API 9 and they were updated again in API 11.